Limit of function with parameter
Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}(x+d)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}-x^{1+\frac{1}{x+d}}$
I have no idea what to do here: I tried de l'Hospital, but calculations are just horrible. Any ideas how to even start this one?

Basic outline:
Define the functions
\begin{align*} 
f(x) &= (x+d)^{1 +1/x}-x^{1 + 1/(x+d)}, \\  
g(x) &= d(x+d)^{1/x} \\ 
h(x) &= x\{(x+d)^{1/x} - x^{1/(x+d)}\}
\end{align*}
We also claim that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) \stackrel{\rm (i)}{=} d \quad\mbox{and} \quad 
\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x) \stackrel{\rm (ii)}{=} 0. 
$$
From this, we conclude, since $f(x) = g(x)+h(x)$, that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} (x+d)^{1 +1/x}-x^{1 + 1/(x+d)} = 
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =
\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) + \lim_{x\to\infty}h(x) =  d. 
$$

Proof of (i):
Write
$g(x) = d \exp(\gamma(x))$ where $\gamma(x) = \log(x+d)/x$.
Then, by L'Hoptial's rule
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \gamma(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x+d}  = 0.
$$
So $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = de^0 = d$.

Proof of (ii):
Evidently, we may assume that $d \neq 0$, otherwise the claim is obvious. Now, define
$$
h_1(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{x} \quad 
h_2(x) = \frac{\log(x+d)}{\log(x)} - 1, \quad
h_3(x) = \frac{x}{x+d} - \frac{\log(x+d)}{\log(x)}
$$
Then,
$$
h(x) = \underbrace{\exp\{h_1(x)(1+ h_2(x))\}}_{\psi(x)} \,\,\, \underbrace{x\Big(1 - \exp\{h_1(x)h_3(x)\}\Big)}_{\phi(x)}
$$
One can check, for instance with L'Hopital's rule, that $\lim_{x\to\infty} h_i(x)= 0$ for $i=1,2,3$. Therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty}\psi(x) = 1$ and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{d\to\infty} h(x) &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \psi(x)\\ &=\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(h_1'(x) h_3(x) +h_3'(x)h_1(x)) 
\underbrace{e^{h_1(x) h_3(x)}}_{\to 1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2(h_1'(x) h_3(x) +h_3'(x)h_1(x))\\
&=  \lim_{x\to\infty} \log(d+x) - (x/(x+d))^2 \log(x) \\ 
&= \lim_{t\to \infty }\log \frac{t + \sigma}{t} +(1-
(t/(t+\sigma))^2) \log(t) \\ 
&=  \lim_{t\to \infty } 
\frac{\sigma \log(t)}{t+\sigma} \underbrace{\frac{t + 2\sigma}{t + \sigma}}_{\to 1} \\ 
&= \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\sigma \log(t)}{\sigma + t} = 0.
\end{align*}
Above, we have made the subsitution $x = t|d|$ and $d/|d| = \sigma$.

im so sorry! there is "-" between them

fixed. let me know if you have any questions

its all clear now! thank you so much
